# Quaternion: composition of rotations. Change of refence frame

Tags: rotation, quaternions

I have a world reference frame, let'denote it with {R}, and a reference frame attached to a sensor, let's denote it with {C}.
The sensor detect another reference frame {M}, located on a marker.

q represents the quaternion related to the orientation of {C} with respect to {R}.

qq represents the quaternion related to the orientation of {M} with respect to {C}.

I'd like to express the orientation of {M} with respect to {R}.

I'm struggling, because q and qq are not related to the same reference frame, and I can't find an easy way to go on. Matlab and python tf.transformations use different conventions, and I'm doing a mess mixing RPY, rotation matrices and stuff like this... Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think it should be as simple as finding `qq*q` using quaternion multiplication. Or maybe `(qq*q)^(-1)` is what you want. Post some code and we might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotate qq back from M to R frame

qq_R = q^-1 * qq * q